# "Cannot match any route" external links angular

Tags: html, angular

i´m trying to make and external link with an `<a href="google.com"></a>`,
but somehow is redirects me to `localhost:4200/google.com`...
I don't know why it is happening but I need to remove that `localhost:4200`..

Here is the html

```
<div>
  <p>{{selectedFlight.logoURL}}</p>
  <p>{{selectedFlight.usName}}</p>
  <p>{{selectedFlight.site}}</p>
  <p>{{selectedFlight.phone}}</p>
  <button (click)="onClick(selectedFlight.id)">Favourite</button>
   <a href="google.com">google</a>
   <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
</div>
```

It seems pretty easy to resolve but I'm new to Angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the full url instead of paratial which will be appended to the current one, change it as

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a>
```

Comment: Gosh that mistake.. I though that the problem was with the Angular router... Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a full URL

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a>
```